# Docusign: Email To Sign Not Being Received

Tags: django, python-3.x, docusignapi

I am developing a Django webapp for my company that will allow for users (or our sales associates) to enter in customer information, from which Weasyprint will generate a PDF that contains all of the information, and allow the user to sign the docusign digitally using Docusign's Python SDK. Everything is working at this point, minus the sending of the email to the recipient to be signed. I am unsure of why this is happening, and after seeking help from Docusign's employees, none of them seem to have any idea as to what is going wrong. Here is the code with which I am creating and sending the envelope:

```
loa = LOA.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[0] #Model in my SQLite database being used to retrieve the saved PDF for sending.
localbillingname = loa.billingname.replace(" ", "_")
username = "myusername"
integrator_key = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"
redirect_uri = "http://MyRedirectUrl.com/"
private_key_filename = "path/to/pKey.txt"
user_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_user_id = 'Your Local System ID' #This is the actual string being used

# Add a recipient to sign the document
signer = docusign.Signer()
signer.email = loa.email
signer.name = loa.ainame
signer.recipient_id = '1'
signer.client_user_id = client_user_id

sign_here = docusign.SignHere()
sign_here.document_id = '1'
sign_here.recipient_id = '1'
sign_here.anchor_case_sensitive = 'true'
sign_here.anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left'
sign_here.anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false'
sign_here.anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'

sign_here.anchor_string = 'Signature of individual authorized to act on behalf of customer:'
sign_here.anchor_units = 'cms'
sign_here.anchor_x_offset = '0'
sign_here.anchor_y_offset = '0'
sign_here.tab_label = 'sign_here'
sign_here.IgnoreIfNotPresent = True;
tabs = docusign.Tabs()
tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]

# Create a signers list, attach tabs to signer, append signer to signers.
# Attach signers to recipients objects
signers = []
tabs = tabs
signer.tabs = tabs
signers.append(signer)
recipients = docusign.Recipients()
recipients.signers = signers

# Create an envelope to be signed
envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition()
envelope_definition.email_subject = 'Please Sign the Following Document!'
envelope_definition.email_blurb = 'Please sign the following document to complete the service transfer process!'

# Add a document to the envelope_definition
pdfpath = "Path/to/my/pdf.pdf"
with open(pdfpath, 'rb') as signfile:
    file_data = signfile.read()
    doc = docusign.Document()
    base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data).decode('utf-8')
    doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
    doc.name = "mypdf.pdf"
    doc.document_id = '1'
    envelope_definition.documents = [doc]
    signfile.close()
envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
envelope_definition.status = 'sent'

api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)

oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)
print("oauth_login_url:", oauth_login_url)
print("oauth_base_url:", oauth_base_url)

api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()

try: #login here via code
    login_info = auth_api.login()
    login_accounts = login_info.login_accounts
    base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
    api_client.host = base_url
    docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

    envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id, envelope_definition = envelope_definition)

    print(envelope_summary)
except ApiException as e:
    raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return HttpResponse({'sent'})
```

When I check in the sandbox page, I see that the envelope is listed as being sent, to the correct email, containing the correct document to be signed, with the correct information. However, the email is never received, no matter whom I set as the recipient. Does anyone know why this might be?

Thank you in advance!